# change php variable values based on select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I would be really grateful for some assistance in trying to work out how to change some PHP variables based on the user's select choice and without submitting a button. I don't really know much jquery which is an issue but basically here is what I need to do.

I don't need to change the content or layout, I just need to change the PHP values that will be used to make an API get request. I've tried a few things based on other answers, but all seem to be a little different from what I need or I'm just not getting it right. Here's my code.

HTML

```
   <form class="choose-item" action="" method="post">
      <select id="select-item" name="my-select">
        <option value="item-1"><?php echo $item_1 ?></option>
        <option value="item-2"><?php echo $item_2 ?></option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

In the below code, I would like to change the $key based on the select which works with a basic form submission. But how is this achieved with ajax without reloading the page or submitting form?

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['my-select']) && $_POST['my-select'] == 'item-1') {
    
    $key = 'jlsDDLfjkcjkfn39209dmxmkdnfn';
    
} else { 

    $key = 'Plkdsldskjf$$dlkjfdckde@kld';

}

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://app.apirequest.co/api/v1/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Api-Key: ' . $key));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, true);

$results = $response['msg']['ITEMLIST'];
?>
```

```
<div id='results'>
// echo results in html table here.
</div>
```

Would really appreciate any help with the ajax or at least be pointed in the right direction because all searches have led to deadends for me so far. Thanks...

Edit: I edited the names to be more generic, so that mistake is not in my actual code but just a typo here.

Comment: You have no ajax yet? Can you try to implement a basic example and say what isn't working? This will be better for your learning proces.

Comment: `choose-item` !== `my-select` Apples and Pears my man. `choose-item` is the name of your form and not the dropdown

Comment: If you give us code with Obvious errors in thats all we will see. Make sure in future that the code you show us is the code that is ACTUALLY causing you problems. Save us all wasting our time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The name of the select is not choose-item so you need to change that if you just want to submit
2. Here is how to post to your PHP with choose-item=item-1 or item-2

Note you can do

`{[this.name]:val}` instead of `{"choose-item":val}` assuming the name of the select is "choose-item"

---

```
<form class="choose-item" action="" method="post">
  <select id="select-item" name="choose-item">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="item-1"><?php echo $item_1 ?></option>
    <option value="item-2"><?php echo $item_2 ?></option>
  </select>
 </form>

$(function() {
  $("#select-item").on("change",function() {
    const val = this.value;
    if (val) {
      $.post("yourphp.php",{"choose-item":val},function(data) {
        $("#results").html(data);
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Yes it would. Fixed